# Unable to find module for EventDispatcher React Native

Tags: react-native

On starting application using `react-native run-ios` its showing error on simulator `Unable to find module for EventDispatcher`

[image]

Comment: have you create new app from stratch?

Comment: try run app from xcode or android studios.

Comment: From last 20 days i'm working on one react native project but yesterday i faced this issue, i tried again installing npm but no luck

Comment: i'm facing this issue only on iOS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189069/discussion-between-brijesh-shiroya-and-suthar).

Comment: After upgrade to react native 0.58.5, I am facing this issues too.

Comment: @suthar did you solve this?
Also, what other react-native packages are you using?

Comment: @AsafDavid:  No i did't, I'm using realm , vector icon, navigation, native base

Comment: Facing same issue here with React Native 59.0.1 using either react-native-debugger 0.9.7 or chrome devtools.

Comment: Wonder if anyone experiencing this problem isn't using Realm?

Comment: Also using realm and I have the same problem on iOs

Answer (score 51):

Stop `remote JS debugging` and then reload the app

It will give you the appropriate error message, most likely missing some render on one of your components. That fixed it for me.

Comment: In my case no error shows when reloading without debug. :/

Answer (score 40):

So this issue happened to me after I upgraded to RN 0.59.x.
I was getting this error when live reload was enabled or if i tried to refresh screen on iOS by pressing CMD+R.

Related issues:

- Unable to find module for UIManager
- Unable to find module for
  DevLoadingView
- Unable to find module for EventDispatcher

Here's how I solved it:

Edit your AppDelegate.m file and add the following code before the @end

```
#if RCT_DEV
- (BOOL)bridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge didNotFindModule:(NSString *)moduleName {
  return YES;
}
#endif
```

This will fix the issue.

- [Link](https://github.com/karanjthakkar/ReactNativeDevLoadingViewIssue/commit/e1a637cd82bf45e6af6814746d863b131b76ac62) to the fix on github.
- [Related discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23235) on github.

Live reload and debug mode all should work without problems now.

Comment: how to fix this on rn 0.62?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be an issue when using the remote debugger with certain RN versions above 0.58. Using react-native-debugger should solve the issue as it supports RN versions above already.

It can be downloaded from the following link:
https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases

Comment: This error is still occurring with the newest version v0.9.7 (released end of Feb 2019)

Comment: @DavidNathan are you using the React Native Debugger app or are you using chrome?

Comment: I am using React Native Debugger

Comment: Using React Native Debugger 0.9.7 worked for me. I still get the occasional error view, but dismissing it (ESC) causes it to go away. @DavidNathan have you tried pressing the Dismiss button?

Comment: I followed @theNinja above and it worked. Even oddly enough the esc button didn't work itself. I have to click the ESC/Dismiss button on the simulator. Utterly bizarre. In my case the error showed up after adding a module to a component without installing the package. Once I installed the npm package I couldn't get the error to go away (until I clicked the dismiss button).

Answer (score 4):

I've started receiving this error after upgrading RN from `v0.57.3` to `v0.58.6`. 
Running packager with `yarn start -reset-cache` / `react-native start --reset-cache` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I have already updated react native to 0.58.6 and reset cache but no luck

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was simply `stopping remote debugging` as mentioned by @Hackman, 
THEN killing the browser debugger, cleaning Xcode and rebuilding.

Couldn't tell you why, but the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using detox, what worked for me was switching the build command from

`-configuration Debug`
to
`-configuration Release`

It will no longer fetch from metro bundler and instead use the js bundle from the build. When I'm coding the tests, I build with debug since I'm fine with occasionally seeing the error, since I like the connivence of not having to constantly build and letting metro bundler do it for me.