# React Native: How to fix error with Button component during onPress?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to add a `<Button />` to my component that updates my component's state by adding a number to a total when it is pressed. I'm not sure if the function I have set is incorrect, or if I have incorrectly set up the button.

I'm able to run the code fine without the `<Button/>` component, however when it's added to my component the app crashes.

Here's my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { AppRegistry, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native'

export default class Money extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      money: 5,
      tomatoes: 0
    };
  }

  addMoreMoney() {
    this.setState({
      money: this.state.money + 65
    });
  } 

  render() {
    return (<View style={{alignItems: 'center', top:50}}>
    <Text> You have {this.state.money} left in your account </Text>

    <Button
    onPress={() => this.addMoreMoney()}
    title="Add it Up!"
    color:"#B22222"
    accessibilityLabel="Add money to account by 65 by pressing this button"
    />

    </View>);
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the money amount to increase as the button is press. It should start at `5` and increment accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the way you're assigning the `color` prop to the `<Button>`.

If you update your `render()` method so that `color` is assigned by `color="#B22222"` that solve your problem:

```
render() {
    return <View style={{alignItems: 'center', top:50}}>
    <Text>You have {this.state.money} left in your account</Text>

    <Button
    onPress={() => this.addMoreMoney()}
    title="Add it Up!"
    color="#B22222"
    accessibilityLabel="Add money to account by 65 by pressing this button"/>
    </View>
}
```

Comment: I made the change but now it says its unable to find the Event Dispatcher

Comment: Hmm - can you please include the code that renders `<Money>`?

Comment: DacreDenny ah you beat me in time. +1 
@Dalton unable to find EventDispatcher is a known issue. Her you can fine solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883304/unable-to-find-module-for-eventdispatcher-react-native

Comment: @TimH thanks for the up vote, and thanks for posting this link :)

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I didnt realize it had remote debuggin on. They dont seem to show a way of turning off remote debugging but i guess i can google it

Comment: @Dalton you're welcome - glad I could help. All the best with you project :)

Comment: @Dalton I would appreciate an upvote as well. Have a nice day guys!

Answer (score 1):

You are expiring an unexpected token error:

Change:

```
 <Button
        onPress={() => this.addMoreMoney()}
        title="Add it Up!"
        color:"#B22222"
        accessibilityLabel="Add money to account by 65 by pressing this button"
 />
```

To

```
// color="#B22222" 
<Button
        onPress={() => this.addMoreMoney()}
        title="Add it Up!"
        color="#B22222" 
        accessibilityLabel="Add money to account by 65 by pressing this button"
 />
```

**Output:**

[image: example]

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/rJo-twpi4